# How do I get a table from a website using urllib2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I'm trying to use urllib2 to get a table from a webpage which has a list of friends (https://api.roblox.com/users/313376/friends). Right now when I try to print the first friend, I just get: `[`.

Here is what I've done:

```
#313376

import urllib2
friends = urllib2.urlopen("https://api.roblox.com/users/313376/friends").read()

print friends[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `json.load` to parse the response as a JSON object instead:

```
import json
friends = json.load(urllib2.urlopen("https://api.roblox.com/users/313376/friends"))
```

Otherwise `friends[0]` is simply extracting the first character of the response as a string.